# Grep not catching the whole pattern

Tags: regex, linux, grep

The pattern I want to get out is this:
A city followed by a pointing arrow either direction ( -> or <- ) followed by another city and then followed by another pointing arrow.

I figured, maybe its because I didnt escape some of the character, but I tried escaping them, and didnt get the desired the result.

I run this command:

```
grep -o  '(\|stockholm\|paris\|tokyo){1}[<->]{2}(\|stockholm\|paris\|tokyo){1}[<->]{2}'
```

on text data like this :

```
tokyo->paris->$NILL1110102.8 fubar$`BLACKFri$$$SunBluePurpleOct011001Sun3.1415
Sun[<-->]0000103.14011010taoNILL$101101010001`3.14153$$$$$$phiparis->paris->
paris<-tokyo<-RedOrange
2.8VOID'$$[<-->]000010WHITEstockholm->stockholm->WHITE2.8taoSunWHITEphifooblah
FriNILLtao`paris<-tokyo<-WHITEVOIDNULLOrange101000phifubarOct$VOIDMon'[<-<-]$$ 
001100blah[<-<-]stockholm->paris->fubarfubar'FebYellow[<-->]NovNULL011001WHITE`$
```

The grep command ive written does indeed select the citys, but not the pointing arrows, which I wonder why and if someone can shed some light for me.

Thanks.

EDIT: Please dont come with diffrent solutions using sed or perl or whatever, I wish to learn my error here, thanks.

Output I get:

```
paris
paris
paris
stockholm
stockholm
paris
stockholm
paris
```

Desired output;

```
stockholm->stockholm->
paris<-tokyo<-
stockholm->paris->
```

Comment: So first off, you should have used `awk`... just kidding.

Comment: Print your output vs. desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **think** this does what you want?

```
grep -Eo '(stockholm|paris|tokyo){1}[<>-]{2}(stockholm|paris|tokyo){1}[<>-]{2}' jozo
tokyo->paris->
paris->paris->
paris<-tokyo<-
stockholm->stockholm->
paris<-tokyo<-
stockholm->paris->
```

Comment: Yes! 
I gotta read up on that -E option.
Btw, is there a way of doing it without the -E option ?

Comment: You do :)  Without it grep won't understand the curlies. And the order of the characters in the squares is important if you intend to match a hyphen/minus ;D

Comment: In other words, its possible to re-write it without the curly bracket, how would that look ? I want to use the basic regex for this , not extended regex

Comment: You'd be in a world of pain with BRE & grep, you'd lose the | as well as the curlies....

Comment: Here's one that works with the bit of data you gave, and delivers the same result as the one with the Extended RE; but it is quite likely to deliver false positives on bigger data sets ... as always with REs:"Know your data".  **grep -o '[spt][tao][ork][ciy][^<>-]*[<>-]*[spt][tao][ork][ciy][^<>-]*'**

Comment: This one does indeed work, but no star shows at the ending, I just noticed, the -E command u gave above doesnt either... But I fixed it by adding the [<>-]*, i just mean u should edit urs